# Angularjs: `$applyAsync` vs `$apply` with sockets

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use sockets and get a lot of messages from the server. There is a handler for every socket message and I invoke `$apply` in every handler. Will it be better for performance to use `$applyAsync` instead of `$apply` if there will be a lot of messages and if so, why? Frequent invoking of `$apply` makes my app slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're receiving more than one message every 4ms ( the minimum resolution of `setTimeout` in modern browsers ), then it's unlikely that you'll see any performance improvement - in fact you might find that performance degrades a touch from the additional timers that are added and fired.  If you do receive that many messages, then you may find that it helps since it will batch the processing together into a single digest cycle.

Without knowing exactly what the socket does it's hard to make a solid suggestion, however could you aggregate the data that the socket is receiving and digest every N updates or throttle the digests to only occur every 500ms or something like that?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using thtorrle for `$scope.$apply`, but it looks like asyncApply is a better option